# rails Bootstrap wysihtml5 can't override width

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a Bootstrap wysihtml5 on an input form.

I haven't been able to make the input width = 800px

The pics show the browser.  If I uncheck the width: 201px; then I get what I want.

If I change the source code that is setting the 201px, then other forms get messed up.

[image: Original page]

[image: After click]

I tried adding this:

```
.wysihtml5-sandbox {
  width: 800px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may be caused by the order in which styles are loaded. If I'm not mistaken, the latest style read is displayed. You can override it with using `!important` :

```
width: 800px!important;
```